# FetchType.LAZY OneToOne not working Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

Spring 5.1.0, Hibernate 5.3.6.

I have Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
public class Client extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, updatable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Type(type = "text")
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "admin")
    private boolean admin;

    @JoinColumn(name = "premiumId")
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Premium.class, mappedBy = "client", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Premium premium;

    @JoinColumn(name = "referralId")
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Referral.class, mappedBy = "client", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Referral referral;

    @JoinColumn(name = "discountId")
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Discount.class, mappedBy = "client", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Discount discount;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        this.admin = false;
    }

    public Client() {}

    // getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Client{" +
                "email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", admin=" + admin +
                '}';
    }

}
```

Have next query:

```
@Repository
public class ClientDaoImpl extends AbstractDao implements ClientDao {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ClientDaoImpl.class);

    public ClientDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Client> findAll() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM Client c;", Client.class).getResultList();
    }

}
```

The problem is that the fields in the entity `Client` with lazy initialization. But when you execute the query above, all the entities are loaded. Why?

SessionFactory:

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {

    LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());

    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect"));
    props.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true"));
    props.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true"));
    props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update"));
    props.put("hibernate.connection.charSet", env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.charSet", "UTF-8"));
    props.put("hibernate.connection.CharSet", env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.CharSet", "UTF-8"));
    props.put("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "UTF-8"));
    props.put("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", "true"));
    props.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_on_trans", env.getProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_on_trans", "true"));
    props.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", env.getProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "false"));

    props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor", ""));

    factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("app.site.entity");

    return factoryBean;

}
```

I run query in `Scheduled` task. There no have a `Jackson`. I not call getters.

`Scheduled` task:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class PremiumScheduler {

    private ClientDao clientDao;

    private PremiumDao premiumDao;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(PremiumScheduler.class);

    public PremiumScheduler(ClientDao clientDao, PremiumDao premiumDao) {
        this.clientDao = clientDao;
        this.premiumDao = premiumDao;
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * * * *")
    public void check() {

        LOGGER.info("SCHEDULED");

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

        clientDao.findAll().forEach(client -> { // тут

            LOGGER.info(client);



        });

    }

}
```

Comment: I try add `option=false` to entities, but still not working.

Comment: Your mapping makes no sense. Either the association is `mappedBy` the other side of the association, or it's mapped using the join column specified by JoinColumn. It can't be both. You should also clarigy what you mean by "the fields in the entity Client with lazy initialization". And you should avoid native queries, too, especially for such basic queries. Use JPQL.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks. i remove `mappedBy` and all working. I write native query because i sought solution. I use HQL. Maybe you tell me how select all rows without HQL?

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation? That's the simplest query you can imagine: select c from Client c.

Comment: @JBNizet i read documentation about `mappingBy`. Thanks.